# How to change string in value using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, decode

So, I've made a form and everything is working fine, however, because I have to use a specific survey system when I add a two words, like "Mary Ann" it ads "%20" in a form field. The form is generated with the `$_GET`, but that is not the topic now.

So it looks like: Mary%20Ann

I'm trying to fix this with jQuery.

This is my code, but it isn't working:

```
$(window).ready(function() {
    var comp = $('.comp-name').val();
    var compCheck = $("comp:contains('%20')");
        $(comp).load(function(){ 
        if($(compCheck) === true) {
            $('comp').html('&nbsp;');
        }
    });
});
```

How do I fix this, so dynamically the spacing can be seen?

Comment: Use `indexOf`. `comp.indexOf('%20')`

Comment: Then, how do I add the html there?

Comment: Nothing to do with php / or css then

Comment: It does with php, as the form is generated with php. No need for downgrading...

Comment: Are you sure that you need to do this in jquery? %20 is just URL encoding for a space, and PHP can decode it for you when you display it, can't it?

Comment: Davey, please place a solution with the PHP and I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just in case anyone else encounters on the same issue:

Davey's comment lead me to the right answer. Naturally, I've had a wrong approach here - I've tried to solve this with Javascript, jQuery. The right solution would be with the PHP, as that is much more safer that client-based language. the [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) did the trick.

So, here is the  part of the code I've implemented:

PHP:

```
$compname=isset($_GET['companyname']) ? urldecode($_GET['companyname']) : '';
```

HTML:

```
 <input class="cmp-name" type="text" name="companyname" value="<?=$compname?>" required>
```

Answer (score 2):

If the value of `comp` after this line:

```
var comp = $('.comp-name').val();
```

is `"Mary%20Ann"`, then whatever survey system you're using is broken: That's a URI-encoded string where one isn't appropriate. The best solution is to use a non-broken survey system.

Very-much-second-best is to try to fix it. Since that's a URI-encoded string, you can decode it:

```
comp = decodeURIComponent(comp);
```

but, this is very much a second-best solution. Fixing or replacing the survey system is the correct solution.

**Live Example:**

```js
var comp = "Mary%20Ann";
snippet.log("Before: " + comp);
comp = decodeURIComponent(comp);
snippet.log("After: " + comp);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, could you please write the full order of the function? Where do I place: comp = decodeURIComponent(comp);

Comment: @super11: See "after this line" in the above. If it's broken there, that's a good place to fix it.